# How to include Automator variables in AppleScript?

Tags: shell, ssh, applescript, automator

I'm making a automator service to select a file, then upload the selected file using a shell script.  I can't seem to get my variables to work.  I'm VERY new to Automator and AppleScript and don't really know much about them, so they might just be newbie mistakes.

If there is a better way to do this, please let me know!

Here's my AppleScript code:

```applescript
on run {input01, input02, path}
    set input01 to "scp -i /Users/jeffArries/Desktop/jeffarries.pem -rp /Users/jeffArries/Desktop/Website_Testing_Folder/"
    set input02 to "ec2-user@ec2-54-213-219-247.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/var/www/html"
    do shell script "{input01} & {Path} & {input02}"
end run
```

And a screenshot of automator:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do it your way. When creating an Automator Service the paths of the selected items are given to the service automatically.
All you need to do is to select "**Files & Folders**" in the Menu at the top (in your screenshot you selected "**no input**").

After that you don't need to use Automator variables, all paths can be found as a list inside the `input` parameter.

After that you should build your shell command like an ordinary string and execute it via `do shell script`.

Try this to get started, I filled it up with helpful comments for you:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    -- setting your AppleScript variables
    set input01 to "scp -i /Users/jeffArries/Desktop/jeffarries.pem -rp /Users/jeffArries/Desktop/Website_Testing_Folder/"
    set input02 to "ec2-user@ec2-54-213-219-247.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/var/www/html"

    -- loop through selected finder items
    repeat with aFinderItem in input
        -- check if the aFinderItem is a file and not anything else
        tell application "System Events" to set theItemIsAFile to ((get class of item (aFinderItem as text)) = file)
        if theItemIsAFile then
            -- store the POSIX path of the file
            set theItemsPosixPath to POSIX path of aFinderItem
            -- build the shell scp command
            set myShellCommand to input01 & " " & quoted form of theItemsPosixPath & " " & input02
            -- exceute the command
            do shell script myShellCommand
        end if
    end repeat
    return input
end run
```

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg